# UITableViewCell Frame is not according to given width and Height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am setting the width and height of `UITableViewCell` in the delegate methods but the when i check the cell frame in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method then its totally different. Below is my Code. I am doing every thing programatically.

```
self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.05,self.view.frame.size.height * 0.08,self.view.frame.size.width * 0.90,
                                                                      (self.view.frame.size.height * 0.90) - tabBarHeight ) style:UITableViewStylePlain];




- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return 1.0;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 5;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 0 || indexPath.row == 4){
        return self.myTable.frame.size.height * 0.08;
    }
    return (self.myTable.frame.size.height * 0.28);

}



- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    if(!cell){
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
    }
    if(indexPath.row != 4){
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:{
            NSLog(@"0th cell Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
            break;
        }
        case 1:{
            NSLog(@"1st cell Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
            break;

        }

        case 2:{
            NSLog(@"2nd cell Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
            break;
        }

        case 3:{
            NSLog(@"3rd cell Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
            break;
        }
        case 4:{

            NSLog(@"4rth cell Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.frame));
            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

The output for the cell frame i am getting is `{{0, 0}, {320, 44}}`. But this cell frame is not correct. The Height should be `129` and the width should be something like `288`. Can some one guide me what i am doing wrong here?

Comment: add logs in heightForRowAtIndexPath: and check whether it is returning the correct height

Comment: Yes it return the correct height. :(

Comment: you are changing the tableview style in here.  cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"]. try not to change

Comment: it is default. where i am changing it?

Comment: what you mean multiply by 0.28 and 0.08 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing, your code is ok. Your cells will have the size you want. The problem is your cells don't know them final size in this methods `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. In this methods they think, they have the default size. But before they appear they will be resized. If you define your cells by code, you need use de dimension you expect,this is the tableView width and the height of the methods (heightForCell or estimateHeightForCell). You can check this, by comment this line, and pressing in the delegate: (also you can see).
    Line to comment to check:

```
  ....
     if(indexPath.row != 4){
  //  cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
 }
.....
```

Implement to check:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"cell pressed Frame : %@", NSStringFromCGRect(cell.bounds));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

However, if you still need your given (predefined) size for your cell, you can always use,

---

**For width**,

> **With case of a custom cell, you can make a method like this,**

```
- (CGFloat)cellWidth {
    return [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width;
}
```

> **Without custom cell, you can always make a function within the same class where you're creating the `UITableView`,**

```
- (CGFloat)cellWidth {
    return yourTableView.frame.size.width;
}
```

> which will return exact size of your table cell. (I'm always prefer second method because sometime you just don't create device width cells!)

---

**For height**,

> **With case of custom cell, you can make a class method like this,**

```
+(CGFloat)myCellHeight {
    return 45.f;
}
```

> **Without custom cell, you can always make a function within the same class where you're creating the `UITableView`,**

```
-(CGFloat)myCellHeight {
    return 45.f;
}
```

which you can use in your `UIViewController`, with cell class name (for custom cell), `[cellClassName myCellHeight]` or `[self myCellHeight]` (default cell in `UIViewController`) in table's `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` datasource method.

---

These ways you'll have your cells exact **width/height**, *whenever you want ! :)*

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width * 0.05,self.view.frame.size.height * 0.08,self.view.frame.size.width * 0.90,  // set the frame for your tableview
                                                                 (self.view.frame.size.height * 0.90) - tabBarHeight ) style:UITableViewStylePlain];

      self.myTable.delegate = self;
    self.myTable.dataSource = self;



    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```